# How to bind muliple row result in single data binding in Windows store app in C#/XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

My database table (Name : Tag) is like This

```
TagID       TagName
-------------------------
1       Home
2       Work
3       Office
4       Study
5       Research
```

I have one list view and its data template contains two text block. One is for note name and other is tags.

```
lvRecentNotes.ItemsSource = db.Query<NoteDetails>("select NoteName from NoteDetails", "");
```

`Note_Tag` table is used for saving `NoteID` and `TagID`
Now I want the result in a single textblock like this

`Home, Study, Research`

So how can I achieve it via data binding ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of a data binding value converter. Using the converter, you can take each value in the row, then concatenate as required and return the concatenated string.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx

Code Sample:
Assuming you've got a model class called Note which has Name and Tags parameters.

```
public class Note
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
}

public class NoteItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is Note)
        {
            Note note = value as Note;

            // Return a value based on parameter (when ConverterParameter is specified)
            if (parameter != null)
            {
                string param = parameter as string;
                if (param == "name")
                {
                    return note.Name;
                }
                else if (param == "tags")
                {
                    return note.Tags;
                }
            }

            // Return both name and tags (when no parameter is specified)
            return string.Format("{0}: {1}", note.Name, note.Tags);
        }

        // Gracefully handle other types
        // Optionally, throw an exception
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then you can set your ItemsSource

```
ObservableCollection<Note> notes = ... // Obtain your list of notes
lvRecentNotes.ItemsSource = notes;
```

In your XAML, add the converter as a page resource.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:NoteItemConverter x:Key="NoteItemConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then bind to the items in your data template.

```
<!-- Display only the name for the note -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Item, Converter={StaticResource NoteItemConverter}, ConverterParameter=name}"/>

<!-- Display only the tags for the note -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Item, Converter={StaticResource NoteItemConverter}, ConverterParameter=tags}"/>

<!-- Display both the name and the tags for the note -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Item, Converter={StaticResource NoteItemConverter}}"/>
```

Note that "Binding Item" refers to each individual element in the list. You will need to modify this as necessary, depending on how your data source is defined.

Comment: What should I put as binding path ? Can you please give me some demo code ?